I am getting 404 errors on a Sprinb Boot 3 application with Java 17 deployed as a war file on Tomcat 10.1 with Maven
My JSPs do not resolve.
Below are my application properties
spring.application.name=codereaper

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.28:3306/reference_tables?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&

spring.datasource.username=reference

spring.datasource.password=Peconic4Bay

spring.datasource.pool-size=5

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

server.servlet.context-path=/codereaper

security.basic.enable=false

management.security.enabled=false

#mybatis

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration

mybatis.config-location=classpath:mybatis/MapperConfig.xml

mybatis.type-aliases-package=classpath:com.empirestateids.domain

mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath\*:mybatis/\*Mapper.xml

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=mappings

server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false

I have tried using application properties to detail where my JSPs are as well as an internal view resolver
he JSPs in the war file are in the war file at /WEB-INF/jsp/*
Not sure why the views don't resolve Eg I get a 404 on the /home view but the error page renders.
I have tried using a Internal view resolver as below since the application properties do not appear to be working
Here is my Controller
    @Controller
    public class MainController {

    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MainController.class);

    @Autowired
    MainService mainService;


    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(Model model,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    MainContent mainContent = new MainContent();
    Device currentDevice = DeviceUtils.getCurrentDevice(request);
    DevicePlatform platform  = currentDevice.getDevicePlatform();

    String username; 
    logger.error("Main Controller:/home"+ " Device Mobile:"+currentDevice.isMobile());

    model.addAttribute("userName", "Username");
    model.addAttribute(platform);
    return("home");

    }

        @Configuration
        @EnableWebMvc
        public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  
      @Override
      public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
      InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
      resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      registry.viewResolver(resolver);
      }
    }

Here is the Spring main

    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
    @MapperScan("com.empirestateids.dao")
    @MappedTypes({Address.class,Article.class,Contact.class,CvxAttributes.class,
    CvxCatalogs.class,CvxCodes.class,Email.class,Events.class,GroupAuthority.class,
    GroupMember.class,Groups.class,Icd10.class,Icd11.class,IdSeq.class,
    IpowerliftId.class,Loinc.class,Lookup.class,PersistentLogins.class,
    Person.class, Registration.class, RxNormCodes.class, Users.class})
    public class CodereaperApplication {

    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CodereaperApplication.class);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "/codereaper");
        SpringApplication.run(CodereaperApplication.class, args);
        
        logger.debug("Debug");
        logger.error("Error");
        logger.info("Info");
    }
    
    @Bean
      public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {
          logger.debug("Debug logging");
          logger.error("Error logging");
          logger.info("Info logging");  
          System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

          String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
          Arrays.sort(beanNames);
          for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
          }
        };
      }    

}

